# component is not defined react native

Tags: react-native-ios

I have created a empty page and trying to import the component of another page into the empty one.

### App.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import {

```
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity,
    AppRegistry
```

} from 'react-native';

import Login from "./Login";

function validate() {

```
alert("Button Clicked...")
console.log("Hello world!")
```

}

export default class App extends Component{

```
render(){

    return(


        <Login />

        );

}
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

```
container: {

    // justifyContent: 'center',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#af522a',
    flex: 1

},
txtText: {

    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#9daf2a'

},
txtInput: {

    height: 45,
    borderColor: '#9daf2a',
    borderWidth: 3,
    marginTop: 75,
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16,
    borderRadius: 15
},
txtInput2: {

    height: 45,
    borderColor: '#9daf2a',
    borderWidth: 3,
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16,
    marginTop: 24,
    borderRadius: 15

},
loginScreenButton:{
marginRight:40,
marginLeft:40,
```

marginTop:45,
    paddingTop:10,
    paddingBottom:10,
    backgroundColor:'#593eb2',
    borderRadius:10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff'
  },
  loginText:{
      color:'#fff',
      textAlign:'center',
      paddingLeft : 10,
      paddingRight : 10
  }

})

### Login.js

import React, {component} from 'react';
import{

```
View,
TextInput,
StyleSheet
```

}from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {

```
render(){


    return(

        <View style = {styles.container}>
        </View>

        )

}
```

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

```
container: {background: "#44c41d", flex: 1}
```

})

### Error

[image]

I have just started up with react-native and don't have that much of knowledge . so, please tell me if any one have any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your Login.js, you use lowercase component,

```
import React, {component} from 'react'
```

convert it to uppercase.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Comment: did implement your suggestion but still not working.